# PRISM WPF (MEF) - Shell within another Shell

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a few important logical components in my application and I am planning to create them as different PRISM shells with their own modules. Though they currently can be independent modules, we might get a request to launch them all from within a single big form at a later stage. So if that happens, I will have to launch the Prism "shells" that I will write now from the bigger shell. Is that even possible? Can I load a shell within another shell (- maybe like a tab for each of my inner shell). If I cannot, what are the general alternatives or any design suggestions that I can consider now. I am still in the design phase of the app and I can move away from PRISM if it turns out to be very rigid once implemented.

Comment: In order to give you better support I would appreciate if you can help me better understand the scenario you described. When you talk about deifferent Shells, are you referring to launch them in separate windows? Or you would just use one tab for each of these shells? If it is the last option, how would the shell's behaviour differ from using Views on each separate Tab Region? Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Currently I am planning to use different Windows for each of the components. But I am afraid that I might be asked at a later time to change these individual Windows into one big Window which would house all all different components inside tabs.

Comment: Thank you Padmaja. I have one more question though: Are these shells completely independent from each other? I mean, would the different shells and logic **Modules** communicate between them? Or would they behave like separate apps? Mainly, I wonder if you would have a separate **Bootstrapper** for each **Shell** with its modules, and then you would unify everything to a single main **Bootstrapper** which I am afraid this would not be quite intuitive to accomplish.

Comment: We are not really sure how the final app would look like. We want to release independent modules (with their own Shells) for now and if we come to know that there are many things that should be shared, we will put them together into one shell. Currently we don't have anything to share among modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load each **Shell** on a separate window, you could checkout the following post that shows a sample in ***Prism-v2*** of creating a multi-shell application. However, it would be quite simple to adapt it to **Prism 4**:

- [Creating a multi-shell application in Prism-v2](http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2010/01/26/creating-a-multi-shell-application-in-prism-v2/)

By using one single **Bootstrapper** for every **Module** would make easier in the future to extend communication between them. You may also need to set an update the **RegionManager** on every **Window** to properly register every **Region** of every **Shell** as decribed in the sample.

Besides the **RegionManager**, the rest of the services provided by **Prism**, such as the **EventAggregator** or the **ModuleManager**, are independent of the **UI** / **Regions** of the application, so you should be able to use them in all the windows without problems.

Nevertheless, if you would load each **Shell** on separate tabs, you could define the **TabRegion** as ***TabControl*** on the main **Shell App** and then register and load each of your inner **Shells** on the **TabRegion** like they were simple **Views**. Registering the **Views** on each **Module's** ***Initialize()*** method would load every **View** after initialization finishes.

For more information about Managing **Modules** and **Regions**, you may find the following **MSDN Prism Guide** chapters useful:

- [4: Modular Application Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)
- [7: Composing the User Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

I hope this helped you,

Regards.